Spring Boot 2.7.18 Error with Request Scoped MongoCollection Using Kotlin MongoDB Driver
I recently migrated my Spring Boot application's dependency from KMongo to MongoDB Kotlin Driver. The application worked fine with Spring Boot 2.4.2, but after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.18, I encounter an error related to creating a proxy for a MongoCollection bean.
Environment:
Spring Boot: 2.7.18
MongoDB Kotlin Driver: 4.10.0
Kotlin: 1.8.22
Configuration:
Here is the basic configuration for the required beans:
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings
import com.mongodb.kotlin.client.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.kotlin.client.MongoCollection
import com.mongodb.kotlin.client.MongoDatabase
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes

@Configuration
class MongoCollectionConfigurationBase {
    @Bean
    fun mongoClient(@Value("\${obx.mongo.uri}") mongoUri: String): MongoClient {
        val codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build())
        )
        val settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .applyConnectionString(ConnectionString(mongoUri))
                .retryWrites(true)
                .build()
        return MongoClient.create(settings)
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    fun database(mongoClient: MongoClient): MongoDatabase {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase("${getTenant()}_obx")
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    fun statusmapCollection(database: MongoDatabase): MongoCollection<StatusMap> =
            database.getCollection("statusmap", StatusMap::class.java)

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    fun categoryCollection(database: MongoDatabase): MongoCollection<Category> =
            database.getCollection("category", Category::class.java)

    private fun getTenant(): String {
        val reqAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() as ServletRequestAttributes
        val params = reqAttributes.request
                .getAttribute(org.springframework.web.servlet.View.PATH_VARIABLES) as HashMap<*, *>

        return params["tenant"] as String
    }
}

And here is the repository:
@Repository
class StatusMapRepository(
    private val statusmapCollection: MongoCollection<StatusMap>,
) {
    // CRUD operations
}

Error:
Upon starting the application, I get the following error:
Error creating bean with name 'statusMapRepository' defined in file [.../StatusMapRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statusmapCollection' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [.../MongoCollectionConfigurationBase.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.mongodb.kotlin.client.MongoCollection: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.mongodb.kotlin.client.MongoCollection

How can I maintain the request-scoped beans with proxy mode in Spring Boot 2.7.18 while avoiding the proxy creation issue with the final MongoCollection class? Is there a better approach to achieve this?
